# Different odd & even Header / Footer by Section in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to figure out how to code headers and footers by sections and different even and odd pages, with a different cover. I'm looking to create something like this format:

[image]

---

Cover

```
No header or footer
```

Section 1

```
Odd Pages:
                         Header 1
    Body
    Footer 1             Date
    File name, Page #

Even Pages:
    Header 1
    Body
    Date                 Footer 1
    File name, Page #
```

Section 2

```
Use the header and footer alternating pattern from Section 1 but with different Header text
```

---

Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you keep the footer and the date aligned differently on the same line using multiple tabs? Or should they actually be different lines or even a multi-column table?

Comment: I'd think you'd have to have a different section for each page because you effectively have four different header/footer combinations. Also, how do you decide when section 2 starts?

Comment: If I understand correctly, yes, it's possible... But certainly does not need VBA. Try asking on Super User. Hint: it's a question of which headers/footers you unlink / leave linked.